# group counting issue with regex

Tags: java, regex

**EDIT: The RE in the original code is irrelevant (or that it makes any sense). Let's say you're matching `(X)|(Y)`: two patterns that are combined in the RE with an OR. How to know which pattern was actually matched??**

I'm trying to extract just the text that's mattching the RE *within* the brackets.

The problem i'm facing is that i cannot figure out which *actual* group was matched, since the group index is *not* constant because of the OR.

Ie in the line marked XXX `m.group()` returns the entire pattern

```
pat1
abcdef2
```

And `m.group(1)` produces

```
pat
null
```

And `m.group(2)` produces

```
null
de
```

And `m.groupCount()` is just a total number of groups in the RE, so it is useless for indexing.

What I want the loop to print is

```
pat
de
```

It's a shame java doesnt have the perl's m/ operator that'll extract the stuff and put it nicely into an array ;-)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([pat]+)1|abc([de]+)f2");
        String original = "  pat1 abcdef2555";

        Matcher m = p.matcher(original);
        boolean result = m.find();

        while (result) {
            System.out.println(m.group());        // XXX want to print only matched GROUP!!
            result = m.find();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is it possible that you want your regex to be "(pat)1|pat(ter)n2"?  The way you have it, I believe, would return any variation of the letters P A and T.  I.e. [pat]+ would match "ppppt", "atpaptpap", and so on.  Maybe I'm wrong on this.  I'm kind of new to regex.

Comment: If your strings were `jjjpatssjpttattpppt1` and `ksjdhfabcdddddddddf2` what would be your desired output? As your expression is currently, the matches would be successful and the text would be `pttattpppt` and `ddddddddd` respectfully. I ask because like others here, I think you may have a poor understanding of what your expression is specifying and possibly regex syntax in general

Comment: only "pat" will be matched for the 2 strings you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that Java does support this directly.

*(Perl does have a beautiful syntax for this, there you could use `(?|([pat]+)1|abc([de]+)f2)` and both groups would have the same number, what obviously is no problem because there can be only the one or the other.)*

So to give you an answer to

> What I want the loop to print is
>
> pat
> de

You have to check by your own if the group is available or not, so this loop would give you the desired output:

```
while (result) {
    if (m.group(1)!= null) System.out.println(m.group(1));
    if (m.group(2)!= null) System.out.println(m.group(2)); 
    result = m.find();
}
```

Comment: +1, but I like to use `if (m.start(1) !- -1)` instead, because it doesn't create a new String object each time you call it.

Comment: alas, seems like i have no choice but to do post-processing after RE ;-)