# Capturing groups using If then else regular expression construct in java

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string in the following format

```
String input = "00IG356001110002005064007000000";
```

Characters 3-7 is the code.

Characters 8-12 is the amount.

Based on the code in the input string (IG356 in the sample input string), i need to capture the amount(00111 in the sample).
The value in the amount (characters 8-12) should be picked up only for specific codes and the logic is detailed below.

1. The code should not be SG356. If it is SG356, not a match and exit.
2. a.  If the code is not SG356, check if the codes are IG902 or SG350, in this case capture the amount(00111)

   else

   b.  Check for the 3 numbers in the code (characters 5-7, 356 in this sample). If they are 200,201,356,370. go ahead and capture the amount

I am using the regular expression shown below: 
Using positive lookahead and if then else construct.

```
String regex= ".{2}(?!SG356)((?=IG902|SG350).{5}(.{5}).+|.{2}(?=200|201|356|370).{3}(.{5}).+)";
```

The regular expression works fine if the code in the input string is IG902 or SG350 (when the 'if' part of the regex is getting matched). but if the 'else' is getting matched, i am unable to capture the amount.

This regular expression is working fine while just checking for a match.

```
.{2}(?!SG356)((?=IG902|SG350).+|.{2}(?=200|201|356|370).+)
```

The problem is only while capturing the group. 
I am running this in Java. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The java code i am using is :

```
public String getTsqlSum(String input, String regex){
     String value = null;
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
     System.out.println("Group Count: " + m.groupCount());
     if (m.matches()) {
    for (int i=0;i<m.groupCount();i++){
        System.out.println("For i: " + i +" Value: " + m.group(i));
         }
     }
     return value;
}

public void forumTest(){
    //String input = "00IG902001110002005064007000000";
         String input = "00IG356001110002005064007000000";
    String regex= ".{2}(?!SG356)(?:(?=IG902|SG350).{5}|.{2}(?=200|201|356|370).{3})(.{5}).+";
    System.out.println(match(input, regex));
    String match = getTsqlSum(input, regex);
    System.out.println("Match: " + match);
}
```

Comment: Why use `regex`? As the format of the `String` is fixed using `String` operations would be simpler.

Comment: Yes, i agree it is very easy to do this using string operations. But i am using a custom tool build in java. So, i have to use regex for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The regular expression works fine if the code in the input string is IG902 or SG350 (when the 'if' part of the regex is getting matched). but if the 'else' is getting matched, i am unable to capture the amount.

You are not unable to capture the amount, the expression is working fine. But if you are in the second part of the alternation (This is not a regex if-then-else) then your result is in a different capturing group. You will find it in the capturing group **3** and not in the second one like when you are matching in the first part of the alternation.

```
String regex= ".{2}(?!SG356)((?=IG902|SG350).{5}(.{5}).+|.{2}(?=200|201|356|370).{3}(.{5}).+)";
        Group number        1                   2                                   3
```

In a regular expression the capturing groups are numbered by their opening brackets and this continues also in an alternation. In Perl there would be a construct that gives the capturing groups of an alternation the same number, but I think thats the only flavour that is able to do this.

In Java you need to check after the expression in which group you have the result.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8180375/626273), similar topic

**You can change your regex and make the alternation before the capturing group**

try this

```
.{2}(?!SG356)(?:(?=IG902|SG350).{5}|.{2}(?=200|201|356|370).{3})(.{5}).+
```

You will find your result in both cases in the group 1. (I made the first one a non capturing group using the `?:`)

**Update after the source was added**

Your loop is wrong, that means the groups are starting at **1**, if you want the content of group one, you have to use `m.group(1)`.

In group `m.group(0)` you will find the whole matched string.

Try this

```
for (int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++){
    System.out.println("For i: " + i +" Value: " + m.group(i));
}
```

Comment: In some flavors like .NET and JGSoft you also can use named capturing groups that use the same name.

Comment: Hi Stema. Thanks for taking a look. The Groupcount over here is 3. But i am getting the value as null which for the 3rd group. 
For i: 0 Value: 00IG356001110002005064007000000 
For i: 1 Value: IG356001110002005064007000000 
For i: 2 Value: null
Am not able to find out why the value is null for the 3rd group.
Also, is this not how the if then else needs to be written? (referring to your statement (This is not a regex if-then-else)).

Comment: @TituJoseph the construct `(abc|def)` is an alternation (an OR). That means: try to match the first part, if it doesn't match try the second part, if it doesn't match try the third part ....

Comment: Ok. Thanks Stema. But, the regex which you had provided also is not returning a value when it is matching the 3rd part.

Comment: Also, the input string could be of various forms, it could match the 1st part, 2nd part or the 3rd part. So, if the string is 00IG356001110002005064007000000 (matches the 3rd part), or 00IG902001110002005064007000000 (matches the 2nd part). Both the cases, i need to get the value.

Comment: @TituJoseph you can test it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vsdk) for me it seems to work, result in Group 1. When you hover over the highlighted match, you can see the content of the groups.

Comment: Hi Stema. for your reference, i had also added the java code which i am using.

Comment: @Stema, i tried this in java but it is not working. I believe regex would be handled differently in diff languages. 
I need to make it work when the input string contains both IG356 as well as SG356. For now, it doesnt matter as in which group the value is getting captured. I just want to value to get captured in any group. WOuld you like to try this in java with the input strings 00IG902001110002005064007000000 And 00IG356001110002005064007000000. Both these cases, i need 00111 to get captured

Comment: @Stema: Thank you very much. :) So, even if groupcount is 1, we need to check for m.group(1), which is unlike other counters in java.